# Google Sheets Api: Copy google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-sheets-api

Trying to copy a whole spreadsheet but I guess there is no api to do so.

Basically, I am trying to do the following:

- Have a spreadsheet which I would like to duplicate with minor changes.
- Create a new spreadsheet, copy all sheets from a template into the new spreadsheet one by one (Spreadsheet copy would have been much more efficient)

Creating new spreadsheets works alright however, copying sheets from spreadsheet doesn't work.

Tried 2 ways:

**Angular:**

```
$http.post("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+fromSpreadsheetId+"/sheets/"+fromSheetId,
                            {headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.oauthToken
                     }},
```

Gives following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

**Google Sheets Api call:**

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo({spreadsheetId: fromSpreadsheetId , sheetId: fromSheetId},{destinationSpreadsheetId: destinationSpreadsheetId});
```

Request goes through without any error. However, the newly created spreadsheet doesn't have the sheet copied.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: @georgeawg Just edited the question making it more clear.

Comment: See [How to use CORS to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors).

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to ask a separate question specifically for the CORS issue, since that a separate problem.

With regards to "copy a spreadsheet", you have two options:

1) Use the Drive API's [files.copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/copy) method. The `fileId` in the Drive API is equivalent to the `spreadsheetId` in the Sheets API.

2) Don't use a "template" spreadsheet that you copy.  Instead, use the Sheet API's [spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) method.  You can use [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to retrieve your "template" JSON, and can tweak that as necessary before creating your new spreadsheet.

Comment: May I suggest that you delete or update your #2? Your #1 solution is correct, but when I tested the JSON-based method it missed several important characteristics of the spreadsheet such as advanced formatting, embedded images, etc. You could either caveat that #2 only works for simplistic spreadsheets, or remove it.

Comment: Yeah.  I'd like to see a code sample of #2.  That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced with this problem, so as it was written previously, the best and maybe the only right way is to use Drive API`s files.copy method. Here is PHP example how you can do it:

```
function copySpreadSheet(string $spreadsheetId, string $title, string email) {
    $serviceSheets = new Google_Service_Sheets(getGoogleClient());
    $serviceDrive = new Google_Service_Drive(getGoogleClient());

    $fileCopy = $serviceDrive->files->copy($spreadsheetId, new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile());
    insertPermission($serviceDrive, $fileCopy->getId(), $email, 'user', 'owner');
    $requests = [
        'updateSpreadsheetProperties' => [
            'properties' => [
                'title'         => $title,
            ],
            'fields' => 'title'
        ]
    ];
    $requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
        'requests' => $requests,
    ]);
    $response = $serviceSheets->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($fileCopy->getId(), $requestBody);

    return $serviceSheets->spreadsheets->get($fileCopy->getId());
}
```

If it necessary, here is `insertPermission()` code:

```
function insertPermission(Google_Service_Drive $service, string $fileId, string $email, string $type, string $role) {
    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission([
        'type' => $type,
        'role' => $role,
        'emailAddress' => $email,
    ]);
    return $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission, [
            'fields' => 'id',
            'transferOwnership' => 'true',
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but speaking about the newest **Sheets API v4**, you need the `requestBody` field in order to copy a sheet.

```
sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo({
    spreadsheetId: fromSpreadsheetId,
    sheetId: fromSheetId,
    requestBody: {
        destinationSpreadsheetId: destinationSpreadsheetId
    }
})
```

Check the [docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo?hl=en), but notice that in their example they use `resource` instead of `requestBody`. I'm using TypeScript and I got a *type error* using `resource`.

Here's a TypeScript example changing docs' example where I **duplicate** a sheet in the **same** spreadsheet (for duplicate, one can also go for the [duplicate request using batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request?hl=en#duplicatesheetrequest)).

```js
const request: sheets_v4.Params$Resource$Spreadsheets$Sheets$Copyto = {
  // The ID of the spreadsheet containing the sheet to copy.
  spreadsheetId: '9MhcPzrWE-Pv9MKhJwow6cWi9uO46RcDTfxhvT9X1fY',
  // The ID of the sheet to copy.
  sheetId: 3,
  requestBody: {
    // The ID of the spreadsheet to copy the sheet to.
    destinationSpreadsheetId: '9MhcPzrWE-Pv9MKhJwow6cWi9uO46RcDTfxhvT9X1fY'
  }
};

try {
  const response = (await this.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo(request)).data;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't have a `destinationSpreadsheetId`. Please consider including the step to create a destination sheet as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of the top two answers above:

effectively, I did the following :

copied spreadsheet with this function
`

```
function copySpreadSheet(string $spreadsheetId, string $title, string $email) {
        $serviceSheets = new Google_Service_Sheets($this->getClient());
        $serviceDrive = new Google_Service_Drive($this->getClient());

        $fileCopy = $serviceDrive->files->copy($spreadsheetId, new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile());

        $requests = [
            'updateSpreadsheetProperties' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'title'         => $title,
                ],
                'fields' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
        $requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
            'requests' => $requests,
        ]);
        $response = $serviceSheets->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($fileCopy->getId(), $requestBody);

        return $serviceSheets->spreadsheets->get($fileCopy->getId());
    }
```

and then used this snippet to change ownership to me

```
$drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();

$newPermission->setEmailAddress('EMAIL@WHATE.COM');

$newPermission->setType('group');

$newPermission->setRole('writer');

$response = $drive->permissions->create($newSpreadsheetId, $newPermission);
```