# How to copy entire sheets from google spreadsheet in nodes?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-client, google-apis-explorer

Hi I am using **[googleapis](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)** npm package for work with spreadsheet. I have a function which use to copy spreadsheet but problem is that it only copy one sheet however my source spreadsheet has mupltiple sheets.

Here is my code:-

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
var sheet_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
..
..
..

function copySpreadSheet(authClient, sheet_id) {
console.log('sheet_id', sheet_id)
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', authClient });


sheets.spreadsheets.create({
    auth: authClient,
    resource: {
        properties: {
            title: "New Sheet " + new Date()
        }
    }
}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log(response.data)
        var request = {
            spreadsheetId: sheet_id, 

            sheetId: 0,  // HERE I SOMETHING MISSING

            resource: {
                destinationSpreadsheetId: response.data.spreadsheetId
            },
            auth: authClient,
        };


        sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo(request, function (err, response2) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(response2.data);
        });

        console.log("Added");
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247650/google-sheets-api-copy-google-spreadsheet

Comment: @AntonioNarkevich it will seem but I still didn't get answer. Is anything I made wrong in above code?

Comment: Can I ask you about what you want to do? You want to create a Spreadsheet and copy the created spreadsheet? You want to create a Spreadsheet and overwrite the existing spreadsheet to the created spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike, I just copy entire sheets from one spreadsheet to new spreadsheet.

Comment: In this situation, you want to use the same file ID of the existing spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, I use existing spreadsheet file id and I want to copy entire sheets of existing spreadsheet into new created spreadsheet. But only one sheet is copied instead of entire sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. In your case, I thought that it might be the same to the file copy. If it's so, you can achieve it using ``drive.files.copy()`` of Drive API. In order to achieve it, If you are required to use Sheets API, please tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172489/discussion-between-tts-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thanks for reply @Tanaike but I have to use Spreadsheet API

Comment: No problem. When a new spreadsheet is created, the spreadsheet has one sheet as an initial sheet. When some sheets are copied to this situation, the initial sheet is left. About this situation, how will you want to do?